# Reasons why a VCR request is unhandled on one machine and not another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, vcr

When I run the tests on my local environment they are all pass. However, when the tests run on a different machine, many of the VCR related tests are failing. I want to investigate the cause of this.

My guess is that the requests that are running must be slightly different. Is this the best assumption?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by "when the tests run on a different environment". Do you main a different Rails environment (development, production) on your local machine?

Comment: Good call that wasn't clear. I meant machine so just changed my question.

Comment: Do you have the exact same environment on both machines? What kind of errors are thrown? Are the requests re-recorded? Some more information would be helpful